# How to convert a text file with varying record layout to XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, text-parsing

I have a text file (generated from a COBOL legacy system) that has a varying record layout. It is analogous to this:

http://www.stylusstudio.com/varying_record_layout.html

What I want to do is parse that text file using C# a get an output in XML format and then load its content to a database. (In few words make ETL operation).

How can I accomplish this task using C# and handle an XML API? Some suggestions, tips, &c.?

Comment: XmlDocument/XmlWriter? Or, XDocument? (Depending on whatever you like more, and whatever .NET version you must support)

Comment: @elgonzo, I prefer the approach who leverages the best performance and flexibility. .NET 4.5. Thanks.

Comment: Then i would suggest to go with XDocument. Google for something like "create xml with xdocument", and you will find plenty of information...

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

1. Write code to manually create a `DataSet` with

- `DataTables` that mimic each type of heterogenous records. OR
- contains a single `DataTable` that accommodates all of the heterogenous data.

2. Parse the records and and distribute them in the the appropriate `DataTables` in your `DataSet`
3. Serialize the `DataSet` using code similar to the code below.

Then, you can easily load the data directly into a `DataSet` if you need to manipulate it.

```
private void SerializeDataSet(DataSet ds, string filename){
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));    
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    ser.Serialize(writer, ds);
    writer.Close();
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a link to the MSDN documentation for XML Serialization.